# What is the idiomatic way to reset some properties of a struct?

Tags: go, struct

Is there an idiomatic way to reset the properties of a struct? For the sake of example, let's say that I'm creating a Scanner (aka: Lexer):

```
type Scanner struct {
  src,
  tokens string // let's pretend that tokens is a string.
  pos int
}
```

And my `Scanner` has two methods: `Init` and `Scan`. Besides that, the package also exports a `NewScanner` function that the user can create a new Scanner passing custom tokens:

```
func NewScanner(tokens string) *Scanner {
    return &Scanner{tokens: tokens}
}
```

Now the problem arises. The `Init` method accepts the `src`:

```
func (s *Scanner) Init(src string) {
    s.src = src
}
```

And then the user would be able to call `s.Scan()` and get the tokens. What if the user wants to reset the position? I'm assuming I should reset the position to `0` in the `Init` method:

```
func (s *Scanner) Init(src string) {
    s.src = src
    s.pos = 0
}
```

All good. My questions are:

1. Should I create a `reset` method or reset the properties in the `Init` method? Is there a rule for that? Coming from a Java world, I would create a `Reset` method, but Go could be different.
2. Is there a better way to reset only some properties? Let's say that I have more than just `src`, and `pos` to reset, it will be very ugly to do:

   s.property1 = 0
   s.property2 = ""
   s.property3 = ""

I'm sure you got the idea.

I thought about using:

```
func (s *Scanner) Init(src string) {
    s = &Scanner{src, s.tokens, 0, /* other properties */ }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is a bad practice in Go, since it's going to cause a re-allocation, right?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `reset` method seems absolutely fine. As a general rule - make it as explicit as possible. It's much better to spend an extra few seconds resetting all the fields explicitly than hours afterward when debugging and missing out un-reset fields. Be sure to add a test for the `reset` method to ensure it resets all the data you care about.